# Expected value of Max times Min of 2 uniform random variables

Tags: probability

Let $U_1$, $U_2$ be independent random variables both uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$, and set $M = \max(U1, U2)$ and $N = \min(U1, U2)$.

What is $E(MN)$?
Find the conditional density of N given M = a for any value of a ∈ (0, 1)

I know $E(M) = \frac23$ and $E(N) = \frac13$ by integrating, but I'm not sure what I can assume when I multiply $M$ and $N$.

For the second part, I'm just not sure what the question is really asking?

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> $$MN=U_1U_2$$

because if $U_1\geq U_2$ then $\max(U_1,U_2)=U_1$ and $\min(U_1,U_2)=U_2$ so $MN=U_1U_2.$ The result is the same if $U_1<U_2$.

Now, because of independence $$E[MN]=E[U_1U_2]=E[U_1]E[U_2]=\frac14.$$