# Expected value of 3 uniform random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

You got $3$ random variables (iid), uniformly distributed between $\left[0, 1\right]$.
$$
\mbox{What is}\,\,\, \mathbb{E}\left[\max\left\{X1, X2, X3\right\}
\min\left\{X1,X2, X3\right\}\right]\ {\large ?}.
$$

---

Attempt:

I found the link: [Expected value of Max times Min of 2 uniform random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523384/expected-value-of-max-times-min-of-2-uniform-random-variables). Can we extend this to $3$ variables $?$.

I know the pdf of $\max\left\{X1, X2, X3\right\}$ and $\min\left\{X1, X2, X3\right\}$. But the expected value can't by factor out because these two quantities are not independent.

Do I have to go through the expected value calculation through the pdfs $?$.

Comment: I think the trick used in the link you posted can be extended to 3 variables. i.e. if you take X1 to achieve the max the Min(X1, X2, X3)=Min(X2, X3) and hence X1 is independent of Min(X2, X3)

Comment: I am thinking that the answer is the same? It is also 1/4 for the final answer. For the reasons just as you mentioned.

Comment: I don't think the answer is the same. Imagine if we had a really large number of variables, then we'd expect the max to be close to one, and the minimum to be close to zero, so the product would be quite small.

Comment: that also make sense @YacoubKureh

Comment: @kuku I don't think that it'd 1/4. If you suppose my last comment is true by independence we'd expect the answer to be the expectation of X1 times the expectation of  Min(X2, X3). Of course there is a bit more to be justified to get here but ill leave that to you

Comment: nice,  my answer doesn't pass the sanity check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're absolutely right about being cautious regarding multiplying non-independent PDFs. However, what you can instead do is write down the joint distribution of the order statistics (in this case the first order statistic is the minimum of your three variables and the third order statistic is the max).

The joint PDF is surprisingly simple in this case $f_{\min(X_1,X_2,X_3),\max(X_1,X_2,X_3)}(u,v)=3!(v-u)$, it's essentially given by the number of possible permutations (that's the $3!$ term) times the probability that the "middle" variable is somewhere between $u$ and $v$. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_the_uniform_distribution for more details.

From this, one approach could be to compute the expected value using multivariable calculus $$E[\min(X_1,X_2,X_3) \max(X_1,X_2,X_3)] = 3! \int_{0<u<v<1} u v (v-u) dvdu = 3! \int_0^1 \left(\int_u^1 u v (v-u) dv\right)du.$$

Comment: For fun, you can also try working out the general case when you have $n$ random variables. The expected value of the product of the minimum and the maximum works out to be $\dfrac{1}{n+2}$.